# How to get index of an item in array list and navigate details page ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a list of array table and I want to get their index value an redirect to my details page when I click on an item, I get an **error**

> "Cannot read property 'sTelephone' of undefined"

I am confused my code is following

on my **list.component.ts** i have

```
itemSelected(item) {
    this.router.navigate(['/details', item]);
    console.log(item);
   }
```

**list.component.html**

```
<ion-list >
    <ion-searchbar  type="text" [(ngModel)]='searchKeyword' autocomplete="on" placeholder="search">
    </ion-searchbar>
    <ion-item (click)="itemSelected(item)" *ngFor="let item of ListData | myfilter : searchKeyword; let i = index" > 
      <ion-label>
        <h2>{{item.Name}}</h2> 
        <p>{{item.Description}}</p> 
      </ion-label>  
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**detail.component.ts**

```
 ContactInfos: any;
  item: any;

  this.route.queryParams.subscribe( params => {
    this.item = params;
    this.ContactInfos = this.WS.ListData[this.item];
    console.log(this.ContactInfos);

  });
```

**details.component.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
          <h2>{{ContactInfos.sTelephone}}</h2>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: are you able to receive data on detail.component.ts?

Comment: this is precisely the problem I think., How do I proceed?

Comment: anything getting logged in this line  console.log(this.ContactInfos);?

Comment: in my console i have undefined

Comment: i have posted an answer let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your `list.component.ts`

```
this.router.navigate(['/details', { data: JSON.stringify(item) }]);
```

in your `detail.component.ts`

```
let data = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('data');
this.item = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(this.item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using safe navigation Operator **`(?)`**

```
 <h2>{{ContactInfos?.sTelephone}}</h2>
```

Comment: I wish to keep ContactInfo required

Answer (score 0):

In your list component

```
<ion-list >
    <ion-searchbar  type="text" [(ngModel)]='searchKeyword' autocomplete="on" placeholder="search">
    </ion-searchbar>
    <ion-item (click)="itemSelected(item,i)" *ngFor="let item of ListData | myfilter : searchKeyword; let i = index" > 
      <ion-label>
        <h2>{{item.Name}}</h2> 
        <p>{{item.Description}}</p> 
      </ion-label>  
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

list.component.ts

```
  itemSelected(item,i) {
        this.router.navigate(['/details', i]);
        console.log(item);
       }
```

Using this code you can pass array index and you can access by the index value in detail page.
As per my suggestion you can pass item id and you can access particular item in detail page by the id. Do not load whole data in detail page because there is only item detail.

Comment: I agree with you, but in my array list, i don't have an id field, i work with indexes. how do i get the data into my detali.component.ts?